# smarty include markdown file

Tags: php, smarty, markdown, smarty2

I want to include a markdown file in my Smarty template.

In PHP I have this:

```
$smarty->assign('text', 'PATH_TO_FILE/text.md');
```

in the template I use:

```
{include file=$text}
```

but this returns an unformated block of text.

I tried using David Scherer’s markdown plugin for Smarty:

```
{markdown text=$text}
```

but this just returns the file path stored in the `$text` variable.

How do I get Smarty to parse an included file as markdown?

Comment: `{fetch}` should also do the job http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.fetch.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead read the file and assign the contents to the variable, then use the markdown plugin.

```
$smarty->assign('text', file_get_contents('PATH_TO_FILE/text.md'));
```

Manual page for [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)